# Граница срезов строк

Tags: python

```
# Пара примеров
value = '01-12-9873'

value[1:2]  # '1'
value[3:5]  # '12'
```

Тут я не очень понимаю, почему в 1-ом срезе строки, а именно "value[1:2] # => '1'"  -  не получился ответ "1-"? Ибо 2-ой знак - это "-"
Такая же проблема обстоит и со вторым срезом "value[3:5] # => '1'" - почему ответ не "1-"?
Ибо опять же, 5-ый знак в строке это "-"...

Comment: потому что документацию надо почитать?

Comment: Это типовое поведение питона. И в `range` верхняя граница не включается. И тоже самое со срезами - верхняя граница не включена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value = '01-12-9873'

for i,v in enumerate(value):
    print('Индекс',i,'=',v)

Индекс 0 = 0
Индекс 1 = 1
Индекс 2 = -
Индекс 3 = 1
Индекс 4 = 2
Индекс 5 = -
Индекс 6 = 9
Индекс 7 = 8
Индекс 8 = 7
Индекс 9 = 3
```

Последний индекс среза не включается.